# Google App Engine & Java : upload files into the blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I would like to know if it's possible to upload a file into the gae blobstore without using servlets, is it also possible to get the inserted blobkey once the insert is done? this is the code I have done so far:

```
public Upload(Blob picture) {
        HTTPResponse fetch = null;
        try {
            BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
            URLFetchService urlfetch = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
            String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");
            URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
            HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);

            request.setPayload(picture.getBytes());


            try {
                urlfetch.fetch(request);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Outfit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Outfit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to write to the blobstore from within your app, you should use the new write API.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to upload a file into blobstore at the momenent without using a servlet.

I suppose if you like you can use the new experimental write api of the blobstore.

The upload example in the GAE docs is pretty straight forward and would suggest sticking to it. Take a look at the [Blobstore Java API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/). There is an example in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Is better with a servlet, I'll share code works perfectly for climbing and BlobKey must capture and store in datastore

.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
<%
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Foto</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input id="file-foto-usuario" type="file" name="file-foto-usuario" onchange="UploadImage()">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="foto-usuario" placeholder="Foto">
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

.js

```
function UploadImage(){
 var inputFileImage = document.getElementById("file-foto-usuario");
 var file = inputFileImage.files[0];
 var data = new FormData();
 data.append("file-foto-usuario",file);
 var url = "<%=url%>";
$.ajax({
    url:   url,
    type:  'POST',
    cache : false,
    data : data,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    dataType: "json",
    success:  function (response) {        
       if(response.success){
         alert(response.blobKey);

       }else{
           alert("fail");
       }

    }
```

});
 }

Upload.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private BlobstoreService blobstoreService =    BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
     throws IOException {

    JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject();
    Boolean success= false;
    String blobid= "";
    Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
    BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("file-foto-usuario");

    if (blobKey == null) {
        resp.sendRedirect("/");
    } else {
        success= true;
        blobid= blobKey.getKeyString();
        //resp.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
    }

    finalJson.put("success", success);
    finalJson.put("blobKey", blobid);
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    resp.setContentType("application/json"); 
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter(); 
    out.print(finalJson);

}
```

}

get url image

```
     String urlFoto = ""; 
             BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(Blobkey);
             ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();     
             try{
                 urlFoto = imagesService.getServingUrl(blobKey, true);       
             }catch (IllegalArgumentException ie){
```